# Create an azure Blob Container name that starts with the $ character

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to create some temporary containers that could be deleted after a while. I want to sign them with a leading `$` in their name. I know, according the [Microsoft guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata#container-names) it should not be possible. They says:

> Container names must start or end with a letter or number, and can
> contain only letters, numbers, and the dash (-) character.

But Microsoft itself did it!

[image]

Perhaps it is a normal container with a normal name but with a property/metadata set with a specific value?

Comment: You are right there is Azure storage containers naming convention that does not allow to use $ in names https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata#container-names

`$` sign is used by Microsoft to create system containers like $logs or $web which are not affected by Lifecycle management. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-overview

Comment: Perhaps naming a container with a $ is reserved for them 

Comment: @Ciccio - this is correct. `$` is an unusable character (aside from system-level containers created for you). You cannot use `$` in your own container name. You'll need to come up with a different scheme for tracking temporary container names (such as storing the names in a table somewhere).